# SwiftUi fullscreen grid device dependent

Tags: swiftui, grid

I'm gaining first experiences with SwiftUi. Although I have already read up on the topic, I cannot solve the following problem with SwiftUi.

As can be seen in the attached image, the 9 buttons should always use the maximum screen space of the respective device. There shouldn't be any scrollbars.

I don't need a complete solution here, just a little tip on how it could work.

Many thanks!

Franzi

[Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQDTj.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve you can use `LazyVGrid` for grid layout. But with it alone, it won't use maximum height of screen as you mentioned. The magic you have to adopt is to wrap `LazyVGrid` inside `GeometryReader` and calculate height from proxy for each button. It will be adaptive to device sizes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The GeometryReader is really very flexible.